# "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/top"... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: jquery, rest, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a REST API (specifically [this Hacker News API](https://github.com/karan/HNify)), and using jQuery's .get method to retrieve the data. Here is my only code so far:

```
$.get( 'http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/top', function(data) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(data)
});
```

and this is the error I am facing:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/top. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using the latest Google Chrome on a Mac. I am currently viewing it via localhost.

I am very, very new to REST APIs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the browser don't allow request from diferent domains, in this case, you're trying to make a request to http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/top from localhost.

You could use JSONP to handle this kind of situation and "solve" the problem.
http://json-p.org/

Read more about CORS.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Could you specify a bit more about JSONP? Specifically, usage of JSONP with jQuery .get requests?